# Volley doesn't handle multi valued headers properly

Tags: android, rest, android-volley, hateoas

I am currently trying to implement a RESTful Client following HATEOAS principle module to use in my Android App. I used Google's Volley in my approach. 
I have extended Volley's Request class to deliver a custom Response object.
Here are the two classes:

Custom Request class:

```
public class RestRequest extends Request<RestResponse>
{
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Response.Listener<RestResponse> listener;

    public RestRequest(int requestType, String url, Map<String, String> headers,
                       Response.Listener<RestResponse> listener,
                       Response.ErrorListener error)
    {
        super(requestType, url, error);
        this.listener = listener;
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
    {
        return this.headers != null ? this.headers : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<RestResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
    {
        String responseBody = null;
        try
        {
            responseBody = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            responseBody = new String(response.data);
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : response.headers.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }
        return Response.success(new RestResponse(response.headers,
                                                 responseBody), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(RestResponse response)
    {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Custom Response class:

```
public class RestResponse
{
    private Map<String, String> responseHeaders;
    private String responseBody;

    public RestResponse(Map<String, String> responseHeaders, String responseBody)
    {
        this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;
        this.responseBody = responseBody;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getResponseHeaders()
    {
        return responseHeaders;
    }

    public String getResponseBody() {
        return responseBody;
    }
}
```

As you can see I try to save save the ResponseHeaders and the ResponseBody in my RestResponse class. My requests all get processed correctly without errors using my RestRequest class.

The only problem I am facing is that ResponseHeaders are not correctly saved or at least that's where I am doing something wrong. But as you can see in

`protected Response<RestResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)`

I am giving my created RestResponse object the ResponseHeaders coming from `response.headers`.

Going through the retrieved Map containing the headers shows me following:

```
I/System.out: Content-Length 0
I/System.out: Date Wed, 29 Jun 2016 17:27:59 GMT
I/System.out: link <https://LINK_1>;rel="link-1"
I/System.out: Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
I/System.out: X-Android-Received-Millis 1467221322063
I/System.out: X-Android-Response-Source NETWORK 200
I/System.out: X-Android-Selected-Protocol http/1.1
I/System.out: X-Android-Sent-Millis 1467221322031
```

But it is supposed to return some more links in the link header like when making that request through Postman:

```
Content-Length →0
Date →Wed, 29 Jun 2016 17:33:22 GMT
Server →Apache-Coyote/1.1
link →<LINK_1>;rel="link-1", <LINK_2>;rel="link-2", <LINK_3>;rel="link-3"
```

I obviously replaced the actual links with placeholders, but everything else is from real calls. Volley always gives me only one link and I don't know why. Is it wrong implementation inside Volley or am I doing something wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Added the System.out.print where it was placed at according to the log.

Comment: what is writing those System.out lines?

Comment: Those were coming directly from the parseNetworkResponse method, I just removed it in the example above, should I edit my question and put it inside again for clarity? It's actually just going through every entry from response.headers and printing "key value"

Comment: @kasolz maybe how they are printed is wrong. have you seen the actual values in the debugger watch window?

Comment: I don't know how to use the Watches properly. Everytime I tried to watch something and the debugger goes over that code, it says "cannot find local variable"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem really lies with Volley. I looked into the source of Volley, where the NetworkResponse object is being created and found that the Header[] coming from the HttpResponse object is being converted to a Map. Since Maps can only have unique keys, this causes faulty behaviour, because the Link headers can be multivalued. 
Imagine putting following Headers into a map, where the headername is the key and the headervalue is the value.

```
link: <http://example.com>; rel="example"
link: <http://example1.com>; rel="example1"
link: <http://example2.com>; rel="example2"
```

Obviously there will be only one linkheader left, because of default Map behaviour.